# Execute command and remove server and remove welcome message

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to execute a remote command to a server, but I get the welcome message and file from my local directory, I try the option q (quiet) and T, but not resolve my issue. I have to keep EOF command, because I have other command and I need the EOF

```
ret="$(ssh -qT root@server << EOF
docker exec nginx bash -c "cat /root/toto"
EOF
)"
```

I get

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-167-generic x86_64) script.sh file file1 Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/ toto
```

I expect

```
toto
```

Answer (score 0):

Remote execution can be invoked by passing several commands at the same time, so that the welcome message does not appear:

```
ssh root@server "command1; command2; ..."
```

If double quotes are not used, only the first command is executed on the remote machine, the rest of them are at the same level as "ssh".

If the line construction with `;` is not possible due to the high number of commands, you can create a file with one command on each line and loop through it with a "for" loop:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for command in $(cat local_file); do echo $command; done
```

`IFS=$'\n'`: change the field separator so that it uses the end of line instead of space.

In this second option the password is requested once for each command if password is required from local machine.

Comment: Seeing your other message regarding EOF, I add that you can include conditional statements as commands in the first solution: 
ssh root@server "cat /root/file1; grep x /root/file2; if [ $? == 0 ]; then command1; else command2; fi"